# The video at python qt webbrowser no player

Tags: python

I've seen the web browser example in Python, it worked fine, but it doesn't play video on the sites I've entered, is there any code that will help

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: It should support the HTML5 `<video>` tag, as long as Qt was built with the necessary codecs.  What web page are you trying to play?

Comment: there is a site installed on the localhost xampp server, connect to it and the videos on that site will be played

Comment: Yes, but how are they played?  What do the links look like?

Comment: I'm glad if you can help me that it's just an html5 video tag, but the videos don't play, it's very important to me                                                <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="myvideo/url" type="video/mp4">

</video>

Comment: Here's the photo if you want to see   https://filebin.net/1f6jqkos45klevee/Screenshot_3.png

Comment: What is the compression codec for these files? QtWebEngine only supports a few formats, and then only if they were configured when your Qt was built.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html